# Download FTP file to S3 through AWS Glue, S3 path is not recognized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp, aws-glue, ftp-client

on a AWS Glue Job, I'm using ftplib to download files and store them to S3, with the following code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect("ftp.ser.ver", 21)
ftp.login("user", "password")
remotefile='filename.txt'
download='s3://bucket/folder/filename.txt'
with open(download,'wb') as file:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % remotefile, file.write)
```

And I got an error stated as follow:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Ran the same code through local and changed the download path to local path and the code works. I'm fairly new to S3 and Glue and not sure where to look for right documentations. Any insight and suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't download an FTP file and directly save it towards S3. You will have to use either a memory-based or file-based stream to save it in the glue environment before you could upload it to S3.

```py
from boto3.session import Session
import boto3
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect("ftp.ser.ver", 21)
ftp.login("user", "password")

with open("/tmp/filename.txt",'wb') as file:
    ftp.retrbinary("filename.txt", file.write)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open("/tmp/filename.txt", "rb") as f:
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, "BUCKET_NAME", "OBJECT_NAME")
```

Comment: For memory-based solution, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/69221348/850848 + With s3fs, you can stream it even directly, without having to keep whole file in memory: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41171784/850848

Comment: Thank you both so much, your answer and comment have unblocked my 3-day struggle.